# PuLP not working with Travis CI?

Tags: python, testing, travis-ci, pulp

I use PuLP in my project and *all tests pass on my local machine*. But *all tests involving PuLP fail when run by Travis CI*.

Here's an example failure:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________ test_scipy_sparse_matrix ___________________________
    def test_scipy_sparse_matrix():
        cluster_object = MaxPRegionsExact()
        cluster_object.fit_from_scipy_sparse_matrix(adj, attr,
                                                    spatially_extensive_attr,
>                                                   threshold=threshold)
region/max_p_regions/tests/test_exact.py:23: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
region/max_p_regions/exact.py:153: in fit_from_scipy_sparse_matrix
    prob.solve(solver)
../../../virtualenv/python3.4.6/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pulp/pulp.py:1664: in solve
    status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
../../../virtualenv/python3.4.6/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pulp/solvers.py:1362: in actualSolve
    return self.solve_CBC(lp, **kwargs)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
self = <pulp.solvers.COIN_CMD object at 0x7ff3e76ba9b0>
lp = Max-p-Regions:
MINIMIZE
50.29999999999968*t_(0,_1) + 80.59999999999991*t_(0,_2) + 140.19999999999993*t_(0,_3) + 60.699... <= x_(8,_8,_5) <= 1 Integer
0 <= x_(8,_8,_6) <= 1 Integer
0 <= x_(8,_8,_7) <= 1 Integer
0 <= x_(8,_8,_8) <= 1 Integer
use_mps = True
    def solve_CBC(self, lp, use_mps=True):
        """Solve a MIP problem using CBC"""
        if not self.executable(self.path):
            raise PulpSolverError("Pulp: cannot execute %s cwd: %s"%(self.path,
>                                  os.getcwd()))
E           pulp.solvers.PulpSolverError: Pulp: cannot execute cbc cwd: /home/travis/build/yogabonito/region
../../../virtualenv/python3.4.6/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pulp/solvers.py:1372: PulpSolverError
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
start solving with <pulp.solvers.COIN_CMD object at 0x7ff3e76ba9b0>
```

It looks like Travis cannot find the CBC CMD solver although according to the PuLP-docs it is ["included"](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/main/installing_pulp_at_home.html#linux-installation) / ["bundled with pulp"](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/main/installing_pulp_at_home.html#testing-your-pulp-installation). (On my local machine I did not have to install the CBC CMD solver. It was installed automatically with PuLP.)

**My question is:** How can I make Travis CI find the solver? Also interesting: Why did my problems using Travis CI occur?

Comment: Travis CI is usually thin environment, so there could a problem as such. I would suggest you do a debug run and ssh to the machine to find out what is going wrong. See if the `cbc` did actually get installed or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes pulp does automatically install a version of cbc when you install it via pip. I suspect that the travis environment doesn't like this way to shortcut installs.
Check via ssh that the cbc executable has execute permissions, if you can't do that.

1) install cbc in travis  `apt-get install coinor-cbc`

2) use the 'COIN_CMD' solver to do the solving

Stu